# How can I hide tick marks on Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm trying to hide the tick marks in the X and Y axes, I marked them with arrows... Any ideas? I've tried everything I could but cannot find the solution.

Snapshot of the problem:

[image: Photo of my problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to do this by clearing out the tick marks after they have been drawn. You can do this by extending the chart.

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        var scale = this.scale;
        var originalDraw = scale.draw;
        scale.draw = function () {
            originalDraw.apply(this, arguments);
            ctx.clearRect(scale.calculateX(0), scale.endPoint, scale.width, 5);
            ctx.clearRect(scale.calculateX(0), scale.endPoint + 1, -5, -scale.height);
        }
    }
});
```

and then

```
...
new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/m9k5goaL/